# How to access a docker container on host from local VM?

Tags: docker, network-programming, virtual-machine, hyper-v, portforwarding

I have a docker container set up on the host with RabbitMQ installed and I'm trying to connect to that container and access the RMQ web UI from a Hyper-V VM. The docker container has a static ip assigned and is connected to a transparent network adapter while the VM is connected to an ethernet network adapter. I am new to networking so I have no idea how to connect the VM to the container. I've tried docker swarm but that gave me a deadline exceeded error so now I'm exploring port forwarding with the docker container or configure the VM to use bridged network mode, both of which I have no experience in. Pinging the docker container from host succeeds and so does pinging the host from VM but not the other way around. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using -p flag when docker run, and then connect it by host-ip and mapped-port on host.